# Taskbar icon not showing until App get focus

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a problem. My application won't be shown in Windows 7 taskbar until it gets focus. I've tried a lot of things, including:

```
this.TopMost = true;
this.ShowInTaskBar = true;
```

In different stages of the form lifecycle, but nothing happens. The FormBorderStyle property is set to FixedSingle. The form only has a couple of buttons and a webbrowser (that gets an html page from the resources).

I'm running on Windows 7 64 bit.

Thanks.

Comment: Your form has a property ShowInTaskbar, is it set in design-time? Maybe a little silly but; did you restart your computer and test it? Doesn't really seem like normal behavior if you didn't mess with that kind of things.. So maybe Windows is just in it's friday the 13th mood?

Comment: Is it only happening to the one app - or every app you create? Try creasting a new test winform app with a blank form and run it and see if that turns up.

Comment: Post code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you, it happens only with this app both in debug time and when deployed via clickonce. I solved the problem by giving first focus to desktop and then to my app. Dirty solution but it works for now :) Oh, almost forgot, the application was downgraded from framework 4 to 2.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with one project I wrote.
No icon showing in the Taskbar unless I forced Windows to refresh it.

It was a call to

```
this.MinimumSize = new Size(wid, len);
```

In the Form_Load that was the issue.

Comment: When you said 'icon' and 'taskbar' are you referring to the icons which launch an app, or the program windows you can switch between once the programs are already open?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem. My experience is **DO NOT** change UI in the `Load` event, like:

```cs
void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Text = "xxx"; // DON'T do this in Load event.
}
```

Consider use `Shown` event.